# Fixing a ClassCastException in a HashMap

Tags: java, data-structures, hashmap, nodes

Hey guys I am trying to initialize this piece of code ClassCastException. 
I read a little about it, but I can't seem to understand why my code doesn't work.

```
public MyHash(HashFunction<KeyType> h1, HashFunction<KeyType> h2){

    this.hash1 = h1;
    this.hash2 = h2;
    this.arr = (Node<KeyType, ValueType>[])new Object[DEFAULT_ARRAY_SIZE];
}

 private static class Node<KeyType, ValueType>{}
```

Comment: Why don't you just write `this.arr = new Node[DEFAULT_ARRAY_SIZE]` instead of trying to create the wrong type of array and casting it?

Comment: I actually did. Just forgot I asked lol thanks man

Answer (score 1):

Quickly fixed by the following:

this.arr = new Node[DEFAULT_ARRAY_SIZE]